# Test a console log function

Tags: node.js, jestjs

1. I have a function that prints a string
2. I want to test that function actually prints the string provided

The way I understand this should work is:
1. store the log in a var
2. assert content stored in the var is toBe what I expect

```
const log = 'hello2';

let myFunction = (log) => {
    console.log(log);
    };
myFunction(log);

const {myFunction} = require('../function-conversion');

test('Function prints message: "hello"', () => {
    expect(myFunction(log).toBe(console.log("hello")))
});
```

Function prints message: "hello" (1ms)

Function prints message: "hello"

> ReferenceError: log is not defined
>
> at Object.log (**tests**/function-conversion.test.js:4:20)
>
> console.log ../function-conversion.js:11  hello2

Comment: I am not sure how your test should succeed, `console.log` does not return a value. If you want to test that a function actually prints out something, you have to redirect the standard output stream to a file and check its contents after writing.

Comment: btw you have confusion in code between log as params and log as declared outside. should be better if they have different names

Answer (score 1):

There is an error to below line:

> expect(myFunction(log).toBe(console.log("hello")))

While calling function `myFunction(log)` you should pass any string instead of log variable which is not declared anywhere (into `function-conversion.test.js` file) like `"hello"`.

I don't have an environment up so couldn't test. But what you can do is:

```js
describe('SearchResultsComponent', () => {
  let spy;
  
  let myFunction = (log) => {
    console.log(log);
  };
  myFunction(log);
  
  beforeAll(async () => {
    spy = jest.fn();
  });

  test('Function prints message: "hello"', () => {
    const log = 'hello';
    spy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    myFunction(log);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(spy.calls.argsFor(0)).toEqual(['hello']);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment Hardik Shah, it is a very good explanation!

Comment: @Kinfol, If it helps you, then, please upvote it and you can mark this as an answer. So other can benefit. Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry, i can not upvote it. I do not have enough experience yet to do it.

Comment: No worry. You can click on up icon near by my answer and click on tick mark grey icon to accept it as an answer.

Comment: The reason i said it was a good explanation it is because it kinda lead me to the response. Your code has this error in it ``Cannot read property 'argsFor' of undefined``
I should have specified that I d not want to mock this test, but I just want to use a simple jest test, to understand how this works.
I will explain in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I pumped up the initial function a bit.
In case one should test a console.log message, he should push the string to an array.

```
let arrayOfMessages = [];
let functionThatPrintsTheArrayOfMessages = () => {
// pushing the messages to the array can be done when invoking the function as in line 19
//  console.log(message.push('hello','hi'));
    for (let i in arrayOfMessages){
    console.log(arrayOfMessages[i])
    };
    return arrayOfMessages;
};
functionThatPrintsTheArrayOfMessages(arrayOfMessages.push('hello', 'hi'));
```

This is the jest test.

```
test('Function prints message: "hello", "hi"', () => {
expect(functionThatPrintsTheArrayOfMessages()).toContain('hello')

expect(functionThatPrintsTheArrayOfMessages()).toContain('hi')

expect(functionThatPrintsTheArrayOfMessages()).toEqual(['hello', 'hi'])
});
```

I would like to know if this is correct and other ways of testing. Involving Jest.